# Constantly losing TCPClient connection from application

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient, zebra-printers

I have an application which connects to a Zebra QLn420 label printer through a TCPClient connection to the printer's static IP address and port number.

We have been having some issues with the software "stalling" and skipping over some of the labels, and after investigating (by adding some logging capabilities to the software to write out to a text file each time it checks the connection and actually reconnects) I have noticed that the connection does not seem to stay open for more than one second (not a solid number, it can vary from less than a second to 5 seconds or more from my tests).

While testing at my desk, this is almost a non-issue because the signal strengths are so strong that it reconnects instantly, but out in the warehouse where this is actually used, in some areas the signal isn't so strong. The function which handles the connection will try to reconnect for up to 5 seconds twice, then display an error message and ask if they want to retry connecting.

I'm curious if anyone has experienced anything like this, and what can be done to resolve it. I understand that the software will lose connection with the printer occasionally, especially in the weaker signal areas. But I would like to find a way to keep the connection open until either I close it or the signal is too weak to keep it going, as I feel this has a lot to do with the "missing" labels and definitely impacts the speed of the software.

Below is my connection code (a combination of my own code and some snippets found online):

```
Public Class LabelPrinter
    Private strIP as String = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    Private intPort As Integer = "6101"

    Private client As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    Private blnConnected As Boolean = False
    Private blnValidIP As Boolean = False
    Private intTimeoutLength As Integer = 5000

    Private TimeoutTime As New Timers.Timer
    Private clntSockParams As ClientSocketParameters

    Private Structure ClientSocketParameters
        Public addrs As String
        Public prt As Integer
    End Structure

    Public Sub New(Picker As Picker, newIP As String, newPort As Integer, Optional PrinterTimeout As Integer = 5000)
        If newIP <> "" Then strIP = newIP
        If newPort <> 0 Then intPort = newPort
        intTimeoutLength = PrinterTimeout

        If newIP = "" Or newPort = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Dim ipAddress As System.Net.IPAddress = Nothing
        If Not System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(strIP, ipAddress) Then Exit Sub
    End Sub

    Public Function Connect() As Boolean
        Try
            'connect to printer via TcpClient, need ip address and port number
            'connects without thread, hangs program for 10-20 seconds if printer is not turned on, replaced with code below to thread the connection and set timeout
            'If client Is Nothing OrElse Not client.Connected Then
            '    client = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
            '    client.Connect(strIP, intPort)
            'End If

            'RRB 02/10/15 - added for loop to try to connect twice each attempt instead of only once
            For i As Integer = 1 To 2
                If client Is Nothing OrElse Not client.Connected Then
                    'uses ClientSocketParameters structure to pass to recursive function ConnectionReturned()
                    clntSockParams = New ClientSocketParameters
                    clntSockParams.addrs = strIP
                    clntSockParams.prt = intPort

                    'create client and call BeginConnect (attempts to connect on separate thread until TimeoutTime has elapsed)
                    client = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
                    client.SendTimeout = intTimeoutLength
                    client.ReceiveTimeout = intTimeoutLength

                    'setup timer with timeout length and start, if timer goes past intTimeoutLength, the Timeout() function is called which closes everything and leaves client = Nothing
                    AddHandler TimeoutTime.Elapsed, AddressOf Timeout
                    TimeoutTime.Interval = intTimeoutLength
                    TimeoutTime.Start()

                    client.BeginConnect(strIP, intPort, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ConnectionReturned), clntSockParams)

                    'keeps the program from doing anything else until BeginConnect either succeeds or fails (due to connect on separate thread)
                    Do While TimeoutTime.Enabled
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                    Loop
                End If

                'if TimeoutTime is elapsed and client is Nothing, connection didn't happen, throw an error
                If client Is Nothing Then
                    blnConnected = False
                Else
                    blnConnected = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            blnConnected = False
        End Try

        Return blnConnected
    End Function

    Private Sub ConnectionReturned(ByVal ar As System.IAsyncResult)
        'this method is called from the client.BeginConnect line in Connect(), make sure timer is running
        If TimeoutTime.Enabled Then
            'ensure client is initialized
            If client Is Nothing Then client = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

            'keep calling ConnectionReturned until client.Connected is true
            If client.Connected Then
                TimeoutTime.Stop()
            Else
                Dim actualParameters As ClientSocketParameters = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, ClientSocketParameters)
                client.BeginConnect(actualParameters.addrs, actualParameters.prt, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ConnectionReturned), clntSockParams)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timeout(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'this method is only called if TimeoutTime elapsed, which means no connection was made. close the client object if needed, set to Nothing, and stop TimeoutTime
        If TimeoutTime.Enabled Then
            Try
                client.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            client = Nothing
            TimeoutTime.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Disconnect()
        'need to make sure StreamWriter connection and TcpClient connection to printer are closed
        Try
            client.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        client = Nothing
        blnConnected = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please let me know if more information is needed. I'm also open to alternative connection types, so long as the static IP and port can be used (over wifi connection).

EDIT: I've modified the code in my program to use the System.Net.Socket class, and the connection seems to hold steady in my initial tests. What would cause this connection method to work where TCPClient doesn't seem to, in the same location?

Comment: are you using a wireless or wired connection? to be honest it sounds like an interference problem (high voltage lines, etc) , or someone has strung cables longer than the allowable length so that the signal is degrading. I'm not convinced this is a code problem.

Comment: It is a wireless connection. The application runs on a wearable terminal which is remotely connected to a server hosting the application, and connects via wifi to the wireless printers using TCPClient. I had the same line of thought initially, until it was doing the same thing at my desk. Out in the warehouse I can completely see that being an issue, if not the issue. But in the office at my desk to experience the same behavior threw me for a loop.